# Can two people from the same company access the same MS developer account?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are new to Microsoft. Joined the developer program on behalf of my company and now want to add a 2nd person to enable his direct access. Same company, so how does he avoid being told it already exists when he signs up?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to use a Microsoft account to set up the account. The person identified by this Microsoft account will be the account owner and will have full control over the account. After the account has been created, you can [associate your Partner Center account with your organization's Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/associate-azure-ad-with-partner-center), and then [add users to the account with the appropriate roles and permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/add-users-groups-and-azure-ad-applications).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Will do as you suggest.